# My SQLite database is not being created

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Below there is complete code of creating and inserting values in database, but it is not working, database is not being created.

**MainActivity.java**

```
   package com.dbtrial1.leenaharani.dbtrial1;
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Button btnCreateDatabase,button;
   private MySqliteOpenHelper mySqliteOpenHelper;
   private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase ;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnCreateDatabase = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateDatabase);
    btnCreateDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //create the database with table here
            mySqliteOpenHelper = new 
      MySqliteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
            mDatabase = mySqliteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select * from Restaurant Menu;", null);
            System.out.println("Main Activity.onClick:" + cursor.getColumnCount());
        }
    } );
     button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        insertData();
        }
       } );
      }

    private void insertData () {
    String BBQ="BBQ";
    String Shakes="Chocolate_Shake";
    String Deserts="Cake";
    String table_name="Restaurant_Menu";
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("BBQ" , BBQ);
    values.put("Shakes",Shakes);
    values.put("Deserts",Deserts);
    long rowId =0;
    if(mDatabase!=null) {
        rowId = mDatabase.insert(table_name, null, values);
        if (rowId != -1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inserted  Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Inserting!",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Database is 
        null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   } 
   }
```

**MySqliteOpenHelper.java**

```
package com.dbtrial1.leenaharani.dbtrial1;

public class MySqliteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String database_name="Menu ";
private String table_name="Restaurant Menu";
private static final int database_version=1;
private String column_1="BBQ";
private String column_2="Shakes";
private String column_3="Deserts";
 private String create_table_statement="Create Table "+ table_name+ " ( " + column_1 + " text not null, " + column_2 +
         " TEXT, " + column_3 + " text not null ) ";
public MySqliteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, database_name, null, database_version);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL(create_table_statement);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//changes in the database

    } }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.dbtrial1.leenaharani.dbtrial1.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create DAtabase"
    android:id="@+id/btnCreateDatabase"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="147dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="160dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="INSERT Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am a beginner Android programmer, so I know that my code is not commented/well designed.

Comment: post your logcat too

Comment: check your logcat

Comment: ; is missing from your create table string on your helper class

Comment: Also if i may, desserts is the correct spelling ;)

Comment: @SafanMomin  there is no error in logcat

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your table name contains a space

The command this results in

```
Create table restaurant name (bbq text not null, shakes TEXT, deserts text not null)
```

This is obviously a syntax error according to sql standard. Now sqlite will not throw an exception but will not create the table due to this.

So just replace the table name as Retaurant_Name and you'll be golden

Comment: private String create_table_statement="Create Table "+ table_name+ " ( " + column_1 + " text not null, " + column_2 +
             " TEXT, " + column_3 + " text not null ) ";  //Are u talking about this line of code ?? P

Comment: Yes.. the table_name variable contains a space. Remove that space or surround the table name in the create statement with quotes. Also end create statement with a ; inside the quotes.

Comment: private String table_name="Restaurant_Menu";

Comment: private String create_table_statement="Create Table "+ table_name+ " ( " + column_1 + " text not null, " + column_2 +
             " TEXT, " + column_3 + " text not null ); "; //Now is this correct?

Comment: Ya should work... Check it out and let me know if it still causes trouble

Comment: Your select query and insert queries will also obviously need a table name change

Comment: Still database is not creating ....please correct this line of code ...... private String create_table_statement="Create_Table "+ table_name+ " ( " + column_1 + " text not null, " + column_2 + " TEXT, " + column_3 + " text not null ); ";

Comment: "Create table "+table_name+" ("+column_1+" text not null,"+column_2+" TEXT,"+column_3+" text not null );   and in your select query and insert query make sure the table name is Restaurant_Name. It's not create_table

Comment: Ya select query and insert query  both are with same name .....but still not working :/ database is not creating ..